# Advanced FullScreen Debugger fails to install during "make"

Tags: ubuntu, installation, make

I need to install a software called Advanced FullScreen Debugger for Assembly code debugging but while running `make` I'm getting this error.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit.

```
afd_load.c:61:32: fatal error: X11/Xaw/StripChart.h: No such file or directory
        compilation terminated.
        make[5]: *** [afd_load.o] Error 1
        make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/vevin1986/Downloads/afd-1.4.4-2/src/UI/Motif/afd_load'
        make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
        make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/vevin1986/Downloads/afd-1.4.4-2/src/UI/Motif'
        make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
        make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vevin1986/Downloads/afd-1.4.4-2/src/UI'
        make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
        make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vevin1986/Downloads/afd-1.4.4-2/src'
        make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
        make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vevin1986/Downloads/afd-1.4.4-2'
        make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Thanks slhck for editing the post.In future,I will make sure that the frame my question properly and indent the error correctly..Thanks once again

Comment: No problem! Have you read the installation instructions? Are there any libraries you should have installed before via `apt-get install libsomething`?

Comment: Was there a "configure" script included in your installation package? What you are seing is probably a missing library. Specifically xaw.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you..It got resolved i had to install that xaw library .. :)..Thanks once again